# Ant cannot find phpunit

Tags: php, ant, jenkins, phpunit

I am currently running Jenkins on localhost on a Windows 7 machine, and have set up Ant to run on build.

My build.xml is set up according to http://jenkins-php.org/.

When i schedule a build, it fails with the following error.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\..\build.xml:127: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "phpunit": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I retrieve the same error, if i try to run ant from the command line.

phpunit is set up and works fine from command line.
(The Windows Path environment variable includes 'c:..\php', where phpunit.bat lies)

Any idea on how to set up Ant, Jenkins or build.xml to run phpunit properly?

Thanks

edit:
Oers solution below works in cmd! Now my problem is that Jenkins does not recognize phpunit.bat. I had kind of the same problem with Ant, where i had to set ANT_HOME manually in the Jenkins system settings. Unfortunately setting the Path variable equally does not work. Then Ant is not recognized again. Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this great guide which helped me a lot!

http://www.pelshoff.com/2011/07/setting-up-a-kickass-development-environment-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

.bat files cannot in general by executed directly

From the [docs](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html):

> The  task delegates to Runtime.exec which in turn apparently
>   calls ::CreateProcess. It is the latter Win32 function that defines
>   the exact semantics of the call. In particular, if you do not put a
>   file extension on the executable, only ".EXE" files are looked for,
>   not ".COM", ".CMD" or other file types listed in the environment
>   variable PATHEXT. That is only used by the shell.
>
> Note that .bat files cannot in general by executed directly. One
>   normally needs to execute the command shell executable cmd using the
>   /c switch.

```
<target name="phpunit">
  <exec executable="cmd">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg value="phpunit.bat"/>
    <arg value="..."/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: +1, just one question: Whats the -p for? It's not a valid phpunit flag

Comment: @edorian sry that was just a copy and paste error from the docs :D

Comment: Thanks. That does work in cmd! Now my problem is that Jenkins does not recognize phpunit.bat :/. I had kind of the same problem with Ant, where i had to set ANT_HOME manually in the Jenkins system settings. Unfortunately setting the Path variable equally does not work. Then Ant is not recognized again. Any idea on how to solve this?